# jquery localstorage save item even after refresh

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have this code here:

```
<input type="text" id="player"/>
<button>join</button>

<div id="tournament"></div>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
    $('#tournament').append( $('#player').val() + '<br/>' )
  });
});
```

If you see the input, you can enter text, click join and it will add it to the #tournament div, now I'm trying to save it with localstorage even if the page is refreshed and I really don't know how to do this, can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using localstorage is quite simple, and so the logic could be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $tournament = $('#tournament'); // keep reference on element
    // if already data set in localstorage for this element, 
    // set HTML element
    if(localStorage.getItem("#tournament")) { 
        $tournament.html(localStorage.getItem("#tournament"));
    }
    $('button').click(function () {        
        $tournament.append($('#player').val() + '<br/>');
        // once element HTML updated, keep it in localstorage
        localStorage.setItem("#tournament", $tournament.html());
    });
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted, but I've gotta be honest i don't understand it, I'm trying to understand the if section that you wrote, do you think you can write here some explanation ?