# jQuery localStorage without refresh the page

Tags: jquery

1.How can I get a value from this input

```
<input type="text"></input>
```

append it to the DOM with localStorage so it will be save even if the page is refreshed.

2. I want to append it with a remove icon option so when I click on that it will localStorage.removeItem(); from the DOM without refreshing the page.

Comment: I think there is a slight misunderstanding here about the relationship between the DOM and `localStorage`. `localStorage` is simply a data storage mechanism - you cannot add anything to the DOM *with* localStorage, it's more that you persist it from page to page with localStorage and then extract the value to append to the DOM.

Comment: But you can append it with jQuery, I've done that already, It just doesn't work for me without refreshing the page, if you want I can show you, but it's definitely possible

Comment: and i hate when people give me the wrong answer, I've asked this question already 3 times, look at my profile!!!, this is so annoying, but thanks anyway

Comment: I'll add an answer in a few mins - see if we can put you on the right track this time. Give me a while to create a jsfiddle :).

Answer (score 0):

Refresh:

Exmaple storage local, sorry no time for expand version (will do later):

```
var dogname = "Skippy";
localStorage.setItem("dog", dogname);
var dogLocal = localStorage.getItem("dog");
$("#dog").html(dogLocal);
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/Andelhofs/59dsL7s8/1/

Comment: No, It Doesn't append anything, I tried to append your dogname variable, I see nothing

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're trying to do something similar to the tag functionality in SO, whereby you tag a question with key terms, add them and then you have the option to remove them. Is that correct? If so, please see a quick JS Fiddle I wrote at http://jsfiddle.net/u7tkoo6n/.

As I have to accompany the above link with code, here it is:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" id="addName" />
</form>
<div class="names-panel"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addName").click(function(e) { // On click of the button
        var val = $("#name").val(); // Get the current value
        if(val) {
            $("#name").val(""); // Blank out the text input
            var names = localStorage.getItem("names");
            if(names) {
                names += "," + val;
            } else {
                names = val;
            }
            localStorage.setItem("names", names);
            updateNames();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    updateNames();
});

function updateNames() {
    var names = localStorage.getItem("names");
    if(names) {
        names = names.split(",");
        $(".names-panel").html("");
        for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            var item = $("<span class=\"item\">" + names[i] + "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-close\" data-name=\"" + names[i] + "\"></span></span>");
            item.find(".ui-icon-close").click(function() {
                var currentName = $(this).data("name");
                var names = localStorage.getItem("names");
                names = names.split(",");
                var position = names.indexOf(currentName);
                if(position > -1) names.splice(position, 1);
                names = names.join();
                localStorage.setItem("names", names);
                updateNames();
            });
            $(".names-panel").append(item);
        }
    }
}
```

CSS (purely for the look and feel):

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text] {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 3px 40px 3px 8px;

    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;

    position: relative;
}

.item .ui-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 3px;
}

.item .ui-icon.ui-icon-close {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

It could be much better written (I was half inclined to write it as a jQuery UI plugin but figured that would probably take longer) but it does the job all the same.

Comment: Again, the 5th Time, I have this code already... I just don't know how to removeItem with localStorage, so when I click on something, let's say we create a remove button next to the value it will hide it, this is so not useful.. my code is even shorter, you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126265/jquery-localstorage-save-item-even-after-refresh

Comment: Sorry mate but that's one of the things that this code **does**. View the fiddle....

Comment: Just updated the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ClarkeyBoy1987/u7tkoo6n/2/ as I noticed there was a slight issue whereby you can't remove the last item (if you added more than one and then clicked the cross on one of them, you would've seen that it worked).